# Prevent WordPress from putting <p> around specific element

Tags: posts, filters, regex

On my WordPress page I sometimes have the issues, that WordPress puts

tags around elements, where I don't want them. For instance, I have this "invisible anchor" on many pages:

```
<a class="anchor" id="some-id"></a>
```

WordPress puts a

tag around it, which inserts a space, where I don't want one.

I know I can filter the content with something like this:

```
function filter_ptags($content) {
    return preg_replace('/<p(.)*(anchor)(.)*<\/p>/', '<a class="anchor"></a>', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags');
```

However, the problem with this is, that the anchor has an individual ID of course, which I don't know. How can I solve this?

Comment: `preg_replace( '/\<a class=["|\'|]anchor["|\'|] id=["|\'|].+["|\'|]\>(.*)?\<\/a\> ?/si', '', $content );` can filter it away, but you need to SSH into your server and find which plugin/file is triggering that by `grep -Rn '<a class="anchor"'` or downloading the site locally and searching with a text editor such as Sublime Text.

Comment: That is no problem, I have all the content locally. On my pages I sometimes have custom HTML-structures and WordPress puts these unwanted <p> tags around it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have something plugin, that causes the problem, because WP doesnt put hidden anchors in the content. have you double checked the post-editor textarea (html/visual) to determine when that `..anchor..` appears?

however, i dont recommend filtering,  instead, save the CORRECT CONTENT in the back-end, instead of filtering the incorrect content on front-end.

use something like this:

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_filter_func',1);
function my_filter_func($post_id){
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
       $_POST['post_content'] = str_replace('<a class="anchor"> OR WHATEVER SHOULD BE THERE,  '',  $_POST['post_content']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I placed the anchors myself, they are not there by mistake.